# Using single AsyncTask to both send and then receive data to/from Python server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to send 40x40px blobs to my Python server, then process it there and send back a reply with id representing the image class (its an image classification task). I use AsyncTask and here comes a problem - the blob is sent to the server but then the part responsible for receiving the reply is not reached in my Android code.

I wonder whether it is correct to both send and then receive data in single AsyncTask. I have read that tasks taking about <10 seconds are fine for this solution, so theoretically there should be no problem in my case.

Here I enclose my code, for Client:

```java
public class ServerConnectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    private AsyncTaskResultListener asyncTaskResultListener;
    private Socket socket;
    private Mat img;

    ServerConnectAsyncTask(Mat blob, Context c) throws IOException {
        img = blob;
        asyncTaskResultListener = (AsyncTaskResultListener) c;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        MatOfByte buf = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", img, buf);
        byte[] imgBytes = buf.toArray();

        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.0.109",8888);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            dout.write(imgBytes);
            dout.flush();

            String str = din.readUTF();     // it seems that it doesn't reach this line

            dout.close();
            din.close();
            socket.close();

            return Integer.valueOf(str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 99;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer imgClass) {
        asyncTaskResultListener.giveImgClass(imgClass);
    }
}
```

And for python server:

```py
HOST = "192.168.0.109"
PORT = 8888

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

s.listen(10)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Got connection from", addr)

    msg = conn.recv(4096)

    buf = np.frombuffer(msg, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1, 1)
    img = cv2.imdecode(buf, 0)
    cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", img)            # here I save my blob correctly

    if msg:
        message_to_send = "0".encode("UTF-8")     # then I send my "predicted" image class
        conn.send(message_to_send)
    else:
        print("no message")
```

What is also important is that I call the `AsyncTask.execute()` in my `onCameraFrame()` method - once a while (not in every frame, only when my blob is sufficiently "stable", which happens rather rarely).

Comment: `wonder whether it is correct to both send and then receive data in single AsyncTask. ` It is correct. And ... If you did not do so it would be very strange.

Comment: `the part responsible for receiving the reply is not reached in my Android code.`. Please tell which statement is executed last.

Comment: Or does android hang trying to read an utf string? Are you shure python sends an utf string? Not a 'normal' string?

Comment: `msg = conn.recv(4096)` Is Android sending exactly 4096 bytes?

Comment: Python encodes the string as utf-8 which android should try to read as a normal string.  You cannot use .readUTF() for that.

Comment: flush() is executed last. And what should I use then, instead of readUTF()?

Comment: You did not tell if readUTF does not return or what ever. Or is there an exception? Unclear what happens.

Comment: You did not answer all my questions. Any reason doing so?

Comment: ok, so basically all I needed to do was to change ```readUTF()``` to ```read()```, what would give me ascii code of the char that I sent from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it got stuck on `readUTF()` part. Now it works:

```java
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int str = din.read();
char sign = (char) str;

dout.close();
din.close();
socket.close();
return Character.getNumericValue(sign);
```

Now it returns 0 when I send "0" from the python server, so it works fine for me.